# Get all combination of treatment & control in R

Tags: r, combinations, combn

I am using the combn function in R to find the combinations of treatment and control in R, however this function doesn't account for order.

Is there another function similar to combn that could account for combination in different orders?

I hope to achieve this in the end

i.e.

```
000111
001110
011100
```

....
(should have 20 combination of 6 choose 3)

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below

```
> t(combn(6, 3, function(k) replace(rep(0, 6), k, 1)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    1    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    1    1    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    1    0    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
 [7,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
 [8,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
 [9,]    1    0    0    1    0    1
[10,]    1    0    0    0    1    1
[11,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
[12,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
[13,]    0    1    1    0    0    1
[14,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
[15,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[16,]    0    1    0    0    1    1
[17,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
[18,]    0    0    1    1    0    1
[19,]    0    0    1    0    1    1
[20,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
```